# Gtav online president CEO confusion?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm on ps4, and I am the CEO of a company, and I purchased a bike club, not knowing you can only manage 1 at a time. Is there a way to assign my friend as president for the bike club?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that is impossible. You can only hire your friend as a member of your  bike club ONLY when you are the president of the bike club, likewise for CEO.

just resupply your business, and continue with CEO jobs like crates or vip work with your friend